# What happens when you JAR instead of WAR

Tags: java, jar, war, packaging

I understand the *structural difference* between a JAR and a WAR file, as is answered beautifully on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871053/java-war-vs-jar-what-is-the-difference) page.

To me, it seems like WAR was just an archive type that was made retroactively to make it clear that the particular distributable is a *web* application, and not just an application.

My question: I'm curious to know why someone can't just take all the contents that would normally be placed in a WAR, and package & deploy them as a JAR instead? It just seems that WAR is an un-ncessary/non-mandatory file type.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not even a filetype, it's just an filename extension + content structure.

I guess there are some tools that expect *.war file and if you give them *.jar they don't know that to do with it.

I'd bet most web app containers instead of unpacking the archive just look at the extension to decide if/how the app has to be deployed. Saves some time and cpu cycles.