# Packaging jars inside jar

Tags: maven, unix, jar, packaging

Can we pack jars inside a jar ?

If so, how can we execute this in Unix ?

I am able to pack everything in a zip, but not able to execute this without unpacking.

Is there any way I can avoid unpacking the zip ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Jars inside a jar is (part of) what a `WAR` (web-archive) file could have, because a WAR-file can contain *anything* needed to make a website.  There is no difference in the file-format though: both use ZIP-format, with just a different file-naming convention.  For more information:

- [Java war vs. jar - what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871053/java-war-vs-jar-what-is-the-difference)
- [Overview of WAR Files in Java EE Software Development](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-3748/aduvz/index.html)
- [How do I create a war file using the jar command?](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-create-a-war-file-using-the-jar-command.html) (tutorial)