# Gradle - How to add war as dependency in simple java project

Tags: web, gradle

I have a `war` file which have classes which needs to be used in my Java project. How can I add `war` file as dependency in this Java project? Gradle pick `jar` file but no `war` file. Is there a way to add `war` as dependency.

`build.gradle`

```
group 'com.asklytics'
version 'unspecified'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "../$localMavenRepoRoot/local-maven-repo" }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.asklytics', name: 'asklytics-mailer', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT', changing: true
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Comment: Please add your `build.gradle` to the question.

Comment: added `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 2):

A war structure is different from a jar structure. You can make gradle pick up a file named `something.war` as a dependency using `@war` in the dependency identifier, but you'll likely not be able to use the classes that live in the war.

Probably the best way to do this is to make the project that produces the war, also publish a jar file, which you can then use as a dependency.

Comment: will jar work as same as war file. It is a grails project which will be used as dependency in other non-grails project.

Comment: When you use a jar as a dependency, you're just using the class files and resources from it. A war can contain other files which you will not use as a dependency anyway. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871053/java-war-vs-jar-what-is-the-difference