# Convert war file of netbeans project to desktop application open on double click

Tags: java, netbeans, war

I have a war file of a advance java application created on netbeans. Is it possible to convert this program(application) to desktop application that run on any machine on double click?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for something like `jar` files. Is that what you need? Check this answer [Java war vs. jar - what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871053/java-war-vs-jar-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: I want to convert an advance java program on netbeans to an desktop application that open on any machine on double click.

Comment: Yes. You need to export as a jar file. Enable this option on your IDE: `Project Properties -> Build -> Packaging -> Build JAR after compiling`. Then your Generated jar file will be into the `dist` directory of your project