# How to include a War file instead of Jar file

Tags: java, jar, coldfusion, war

First of all I am a ColdFusion developer and do not really know how Java works.

I have a situation whereby we need to integrate a Java client file into a project that is hosted by a ColdFusion 9 server, with JRun application server, and it need AXIS 2 request for Encrypt / Descrypt a SOAP content.

When we compile the Java client file into a **.JAR** file, we encounter a jar file compatible issue with the ColdFusion / JRun server library.

We are attempting to use a **.WAR** file generated via MAVEN instead of .JAR file. We have proved that the .JAR files resolved the compatibility issue and is working in the JAVA environment (jsp page).

My question :
How can I include the **.WAR** into my ColdFusion page? I can't find any samples or references anywhere.

Should I just place the .WAR file into the `[coldfusion_server]/lib` folder and call it by using `cfobject` = Java?

Like:

```
<cfset myObj = createObject("java", "class_path")>
```

Any samples or references I can review will be helpful for me.

---

2017-04-19 - Update -

Below is our test case and result when using **JAR file** created by our Java professional resource:

I deployed IBAN Client application in ColdFusion server directory 
(C:\JRun4\lib\IbanWs-Client.jar)

Note : This Client Application is using SOAP (AXIS2 web services) + CXF 2.7.3 + WSS4J 1.6.18.

This Client application is working as expected as in **ColdFusion 2016** server and standalone application.

The same application **is not working in ColdFusion 9 server** and we are facing a few issues.  Error logs are specified in end of the document.

**ColdFusion 9 server is using older version jar while server start-up**. This behavior is **causing libraries mismatch issue**.

Steps followed to reproduce the issue.

1. Deploy client application in JRun server lib directory

   C:\JRun4\lib\IbanWs-Client.jar
2. Upgrade webservices.jar in  in JRun server lib directory

   C:\JRun4\lib\webservices.jar (Axis 2 soap)

   a.  Extract jrun\lib\webservices.jar file to a folder one.

   b.  Extract axis2 jar file to a folder  two.

   c.  Copy the  com folder  from folder two  and paste in folder one

   d.  Copy the  javax folder  from folder two  and paste in folder one

   e.  Create the jar using folder one contents :

```html
 jar cvf webservices.jar
```

3. Developed IbanValidate.cfm file to access IBAN Services using
   IbanWs-Client.jar.
4. Copy project dependent jar files to the *C:\JRun4\lib* directory.
5. Calling the banWs-Client.jar by using below cfm script :

```html
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Welcome to IBAN Web Application</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
 <cfobject action=create type=java class=com.tfp.ipr.soap.IBANClient name=obj> 
 <cfset StringVal2=obj.IbanValidate(javaCast("string","FR14200410100xxxxxxxx"))> 

<cfoutput> 
<br> IBAN  :  #StringVal2.getInstitutionDetail().getIban()#<br> 
<br> Title  :     #StringVal2.getInstitutionDetail().getInstTitle()#<br> 
<br> SWIFT/BIC  : #StringVal2.getInstitutionDetail().getSwiftBic()#<br> 
<br> BranchCode  : #StringVal2.getInstitutionDetail().getBranchCode()#<br> 
<br> Street  : #StringVal2.getInstitutionDetail().getStreet()#<br> 
<br> CountryCode :#StringVal2.getInstitutionDetail().getCountryCode()# <br>
</cfoutput><br> 
</body> 
</html>
```

6. The CFM page return response as below :

```html
 unknown parameter type.
 
The error occurred in C:/project_dev/IbanValidate.cfm: line 7

5 : <body> 
6 :  <cfobject action=create type=java class=com.tfp.ipr.soap.IBANClient name=obj> 
7 :  <cfset StringVal2=obj.IbanValidate(javaCast("string","FR142004101XXXXXXXX"))> 
8 : 
9 : <!--- Display the results---> 

Resources:

    Check the ColdFusion documentation to verify that you are using the correct syntax.
    Search the Knowledge Base to find a solution to your problem.

Browser    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Remote Address    127.0.0.1
Referrer    http..xxx.com/project_dev/
Date/Time    19-Apr-17 07:53 AM
Stack Trace
at cfIbanValidate2ecfm1956923455.runPage(C:/project_dev/IbanValidate.cfm:7)

javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: unknown parameter type.
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:155)
 at $Proxy32.validate(Unknown Source)
 at com.tfp.ipr.soap.IBANClient.IbanValidate(IBANClient.java:37)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.invoke(JavaProxy.java:97)
 at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2360)
 at cfIbanValidate2ecfm1956923455.runPage(C:/project_dev/IbanValidate.cfm:7)
 at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
 at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
 at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
 at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:381)
 at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
 at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
 at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:94)
 at coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:27)
 at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
 at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:79)
 at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
 at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
 at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
 at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
 at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
 at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
 at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:200)
 at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
 at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
 at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
 at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
 at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
 at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
 at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
 at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
 at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
 at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
 at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
 at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
 at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown parameter type.
 at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCERSACipher.engineInit(Unknown Source)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
 at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecEncryptedKey.prepareInternal(WSSecEncryptedKey.java:257)
 at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecEncrypt.prepare(WSSecEncrypt.java:182)
 at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.doEncryption(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java:420)
 at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.doSignBeforeEncrypt(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java:190)
 at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.handleBinding(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java:98)
 at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:165)
 at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:89)
 at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
 at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:133)
 ... 39 more
```

Appreciate anyone can help me to resolve this issue.

Thank and have a nice day.

Comment: A [.war file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871053/java-war-vs-jar-what-is-the-difference) is more of a separate application. Can you post more details about this library you are trying to integrate? 1. What java library are you trying to use? 2. How did you try and use the .jar's and exactly what "compatibility" issues are you having? Please [edit] the question to include your code and any error messages.

Comment: Hi Leigh, Thank for your comment. I has amend my question with the Jars file test result when involve coldfusion file.

Comment: (Edit) I am not sure you can successfully use a lib that requires Axis2 under CF9 since it is already bundled with Axis1.x. I do not know what impact upgrading the built in version might have (ie if it will break other things). It probably works in 2016, because CF10+ already use Axis2.  If this is just a soap web service, you could always try the cfhttp + xml route instead of the java client. Look into SoapUI for generating the xml.

Comment: If you absolutely must use the java client, another possibility is to try loading the jar with the [JavaLoader.cfc](https://github.com/markmandel/JavaLoader). Essentially it creates a separate class loader from the main CF class loader, which *might* help resolve the conflicts.

Comment: Hi Leigh, Thank for your comment. It is soap web service request with encypt / decrypt request. It only can work with Java client file as it not work with cfhttp. I will try javaloder.cfc approach to see whether it workable or not.. Thank for your advice.