# How to generate a runnable web-app war/jar using Vaadin Flow and Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm writing a project using Vaadin Flow (13), Gradle and the gradle-vaadin-flow plugin. I'm using Gretty as well. I am unable to generate a runnable jar o war file of the project.

I've tried the `./gradlew -Dvaadin.productionMode war` command, but the generate war is not runnable.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a war file like you can execute a runnable jar-file.
You need to deploy it.

You can see [This Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5871102/5692287) for further information about the differences.