# Add servlet in a java library

Tags: java, jsp, web, servlets, java-server

I have created a java library that fetches data from Elasticsearch cluster and shows hits. Is it possible to add a servlet and UI page in the same library, without creating another dynamic web project?

Comment: How does your library look? I assume a couple of classes that expose methods which fetch data and show them? Where do they show them?

Comment: They'll be shown in another service.

Comment: Ok. In general, the answer to your question is - yes, it is possible add servlet to your library. You would in that case have to create a [war file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871053/difference-between-jar-and-war-in-java) and deploy it to a servlet container.